# Recyclerview not showing items Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, pagination

My App is just shows an Empty Screen and `RecyclerView` is not showing anything or is not working but there are no compile time or run time errors.

It would be great help if I get an answer ...
I have been making an app that uses a `RecyclerView` but it's not showing any thing..why contents of the recycler view have not been showing up.my codes are bellow

Here is My FeedFragment, Adapter

```
//Fragment

@AndroidEntryPoint
class FeedFragment : Fragment(R.layout.feed_fragment) {

    private var _binding: FeedFragmentBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var feedAdapter: FeedAdapter
    private val viewModel: FeedViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FeedFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val view = binding.root
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        setupRv()
        getCharacters()
    }

    private fun getCharacters() {
        viewModel.listData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { pagingData ->
                feedAdapter.submitData(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle, pagingData)
        })
    }


    private fun setupRv() {
        feedAdapter = FeedAdapter()
        binding.feedRv.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        binding.feedRv.apply {
            adapter = feedAdapter
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}

//PagingDataAdapter

class FeedAdapter : PagingDataAdapter<Characters,FeedAdapter.FeedViewHolder >(DiffCallback()) {

    inner class FeedViewHolder(private val binding: FeedFragmentRvBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
                fun bind(characters: Characters) {
                    with(binding) {

                        Glide.with(itemView)
                            .load(characters.image)
                            .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                            .into(feedRvImage)
                        feedRvName.text = characters.name
                        feedRvStatus.text = characters.status
                        feedRvSpecies.text = characters.species
                        feedRvGender.text = characters.gender

                        println(characters.name)


                    }
                }
            }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FeedViewHolder {
        val binding =
            FeedFragmentRvBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false)
        return FeedViewHolder(binding)
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FeedViewHolder, position: Int) {

        getItem(position)?.let { holder.bind(it) }
    }


    class DiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Characters>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Characters, newItem: Characters): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Characters, newItem: Characters): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```

// retrofit response

[image: retrofit response]

Comment: https://github.com/ElmarShkrv/RickAndMortyApp
all project files

Comment: Are you getting logs.... Chracter name

Comment: Parsing issue or View hidden... Cross check your response and views visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `CharacterResponse` model class to parse data accordingly.

```
data class CharacterResponse(
    val info: Info,
    val results: List<Characters>
)
```

Comment: I wasted three days thank you so much you saved my life :)